# Code giving runtime error?

Tags: c

```
i am trying to solve leetcode question :-
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/
Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number.

For example, given [3, 30, 34, 5, 9], the largest formed number is 9534330.
i am trying to sort strings by defining comparator  to compare strings by concatinating right-to-left or left-to-right.

The program is giving runtime error. Please help....

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b){
        int p = *((int *)a);
        int q = *((int *)b);
        int size = 14;
        char * first = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        char * second = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        first[0] = "\0";
        second[0] = "\0";
        sprintf(first, "%d",p);
        sprintf(first, "%d",q);
        sprintf(second, "%d",q);
        sprintf(second, "%d",p);
        return -1*strcmp(first, second);
    }

    char* largestNumber(int* nums, int numsSize) {
        if(numsSize <=0)
            return NULL;
        qsort(nums, numsSize, sizeof(int), comp);
        char * result = (char*)malloc(numsSize *5*sizeof(char));
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<numsSize; i++)
            result = strcat(result, nums[i]);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The `comp` do cause memory leak.

Comment: You have to initialize the buffer pointed by `result` before passing it to `strcat()`.

Comment: You shouldn't do `first[0] = "\0";`, which is assigning an pointer to the element, whose type is `char`. Also, it is completely meaningless because it will be overwritten by `sprintf(first, "%d",q);`. `sprintf(first, "%d",p);` is useless, too. The same thing can by said for `second`.

Comment: What is the purpose of overwriting  `first` and `second`? I mean, you first write `p` to `first`, then you write `q` to `first`, why? And if you have two integers, why compare them as strings? You can just do `return p - q;` (or `return q - p;` depending on order wanted).

Comment: And are you sure you want to concatenate with `strcat` an array of `char` and an `int`

Answer (score 1):

- Allocating memory with `malloc()` and throwing it away is a bad practice.
  Since you always allocate fixed amount of memory in `comp`, use regular array.
- Don't do `first[0] = "\0";`, which is assigning an pointer to `char` variable.
  Also remove useless `sprintf`, whose result is soon be overwritten.
- Allocating 5 bytes for each elements may be too small if `int` has 4 bytes. Allocate more memory.
- Initialize the buffer pointed by `result` before passing it to `strcat()`.
- Convert the integer to string before passing it to `strcat()`.
- They say that [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Possible fix (not tested):

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b){
    int p = *((int *)a);
    int q = *((int *)b);
    char first[14];
    char second[14];
    sprintf(first, "%d", q);
    sprintf(second, "%d", p);
    return -1 * strcmp(first, second);
}

char* largestNumber(int* nums, int numsSize) {
    if(numsSize <= 0)
        return NULL;
    qsort(nums, numsSize, sizeof(int), comp);
    char * result = malloc(numsSize * 14 * sizeof(char));
    int i;
    result[0] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        char num[14];
        sprintf(num, "%d", nums[i]);
        result = strcat(result, num);
    }
    return result;
}
```